# Burn A (Video) DVD In .NET Without 3rd Party Libraries

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dvd-burning

Maybe this is a stupid question....I'm looking at a project that would require me to burn a video to DVD in such a way that a traditional DVD player could play it.  I've found several '3rd party tools' that do this, which is great and the direction I'll probably take.

But, I can't, for the life of me, fathom how to sit down and write a video to DVD.

I know this is largely academic (Just use the available libraries!) still, I'd really like some direction on how I would/could go about doing this myself.

Comment: As a starting point, you'll probably need to buy some laser and high-precision measurement tools!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to talk directly to Windows then you're going to have to run through the [Image Mastering API (IMAPI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366450%28VS.85%29.aspx). Some people have [written wrappers](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/net/code/libraries/writing_cds/imapi/article.asp) for it. IMAPIv2 was released for Vista so I'm not 100% sure of its progression to Windows 7.

But that will just allow you to write files to disk. To understand how to burn a video DVD to disk you'll have to understand video encoding, the MPEG-2 spec, the UDF bridge file format and a couple of other things. I would highly recommend looking into a command-line video converter that can create the `VIDEO_TS` file structure for you and **then** use the Windows API to write that to disk.

**EDIT**

[Here's another wrapper.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/imapi2.aspx)

Comment: This is commonly referred to as "Authoring" a DVD.  Authoring from raw video is not a trivial task as Chris has pointed out.

Comment: IMAPIv2 is available as an optional download for XP and ships with Win7. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/932716

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend looking at a project like [SharpRecorder](http://code.google.com/p/sharprecorder/) and understanding its code as a start.

Since there is no native support in .NET for writing a DVD video file you'll need to look at the [DVD specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD#Specifications) and start from the ground up. That is why looking at a library or using one is a great start (why reinvent the wheel?).

Comment: I think OP is hoping to use built-in Windows APIs (first-party libraries).

Comment: @Gabe Is there a first party API for writing a DVD-Video disc?

Comment: @Gabe IMAPI will enable him to write an image to the disk, but he would still need to construct a compliant DVD-Video Image first.

Comment: No, IMAPI lets you create a DVD-Video image just by giving it the individual MPEG-2 and other files. Of course it doesn't create the video and menu files for you, but neither does SharpRecorder.